# boost::json multiple definition of.... when linking (header only)

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using boost no Ubuntu to define a class. One of my class methods uses boost json type:

**MyClass.hpp**

```
#pragma once 

#include <boost/json/src.hpp>

class MyClass
{
private:
    static void publish(boost::json::object json);

public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include <stdio>

#include "MyClass.hpp"

void MyClass::publish(boost::json::object json)
{
   // Does nothing
   std::cout << "Here" << std::endl;
}
```

Building compiles the class, but after that I'm getting multiple linking errors:

```
.
.
.
.
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::value_ref::write_array(boost::json::value*, std::initializer_list<boost::json::value_ref>, boost::json::storage_ptr const&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/value_ref.ipp:164: multiple definition of `boost::json::value_ref::write_array(boost::json::value*, std::initializer_list<boost::json::value_ref>, boost::json::storage_ptr const&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/value_ref.ipp:164: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::array(std::initializer_list<boost::json::value_ref>, boost::json::storage_ptr)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:312: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::array(std::initializer_list<boost::json::value_ref>, boost::json::storage_ptr)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:312: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::operator=(boost::json::array const&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:340: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::operator=(boost::json::array const&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:340: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::swap(boost::json::array&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:592: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::swap(boost::json::array&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:592: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::operator=(boost::json::array&&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:349: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::operator=(boost::json::array&&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:349: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::operator=(std::initializer_list<boost::json::value_ref>)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:359: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::operator=(std::initializer_list<boost::json::value_ref>)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:359: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::shrink_to_fit()':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:374: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::shrink_to_fit()'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:374: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::clear()':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:418: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::clear()'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:418: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::insert(boost::json::value const*, boost::json::value const&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:432: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::insert(boost::json::value const*, boost::json::value const&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:432: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::insert(boost::json::value const*, boost::json::value&&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:442: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::insert(boost::json::value const*, boost::json::value&&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:442: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::insert(boost::json::value const*, unsigned long, boost::json::value const&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:453: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::insert(boost::json::value const*, unsigned long, boost::json::value const&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:453: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::insert(boost::json::value const*, std::initializer_list<boost::json::value_ref>)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:471: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::insert(boost::json::value const*, std::initializer_list<boost::json::value_ref>)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:471: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::erase(boost::json::value const*)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:484: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::erase(boost::json::value const*)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:484: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::erase(boost::json::value const*, boost::json::value const*)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:497: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::erase(boost::json::value const*, boost::json::value const*)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:497: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::push_back(boost::json::value const&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:518: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::push_back(boost::json::value const&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:518: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/MyClass.o: in function `boost::json::array::push_back(boost::json::value&&)':
/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:525: multiple definition of `boost::json::array::push_back(boost::json::value&&)'; obj/main.o:/usr/include/boost/json/impl/array.ipp:525: first defined here
.
.
.
```

I'm stuck that for hours... Moving the include to the .cpp works, but I need to use `boost::json` on my header...

I think `#pragma once` would solve it, but it's not being the case.. No idea on how to solve it.

Comment: Humm.... So basically I cannot use boost types on my class method?

Comment: no, you just need to use the right header as specified in the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/overview.html#json.overview.requirements.header_only

`#include <boost/json/src.hpp>` must be used in a single source file, it should not be in a header file, you should use `#include <boost/json.hpp>` instead.